# How does PuLP linear programming solver work?

Tags: python

I am curious about the algorithm in the PuLP 
Is this LPsolver is using the simplex method?

Answer (score 0):

PuLP provides a convenient frontend for a number of solvers. Some of these solvers may use simplex, others may not. You can specify the solver in order to better control this, but you'd need to look at the details for the individual solvers to figure out if any meet your criteria.